# Angular 2+ timer function is not working in one of the components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is very very very strange. I got an timer function which works on all my components except 1. But I just don't know why, I also don't get any errors or something.

What am I missing? The code that I use looks like this:

The HTML

```
<p>Time in miliseconds: <b id="tick">{{time}}</b></p>
```

and in my protected.component.ts

```
timeBegin = new Date();
  starts = null;
  time = '00:00:00.000';

GetUser(): void {
    this.startTime();
    this.dataService.getUser().subscribe(res => {
      if (res !== undefined) {
        this.dataIsReady = true;
        this.imgSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + res['image'];
      }
    });
    this.stopTime();
  }

public clockRun() {
const currentTime = new Date();
const timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - this.timeBegin.getTime());
const hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours();
const min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
const sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
const ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

this.time =
    (hour > 9 ? hour : '0' + hour) + ':' +
    (min > 9 ? min : '0' + min) + ':' +
    (sec > 9 ? sec : '0' + sec) + '.' +
    (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? '0' + ms : '0' + ms);


}

  startTime() {
    this.timeBegin = new Date();

    this.starts = setInterval(this.clockRun.bind(this), 10);
  }

  stopTime() {
    clearInterval(this.starts);
  }
```

Comment: How many components are using it successfully?

Comment: three other components

Comment: What output are you seeing for the component that is not working?

Comment: @ChristianSantos no it works. The GetUser() component also gets the image and shows on screen. thats whats the most crazy about it.

Comment: this.stopTime outside subscribe()?

Comment: I see the problem now, after the page is done loading, it automatically runs the GetUser() function for no reason. When I delete the (click) function from template it doesn't call the function but I can't try the time -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could simplify it a bit. For example:
In HTML better to use DatePipe, like:

```
{{ interval | date:'HH:mm:ss SSS':'+0000'}}
```

In Component:

```
  timeBegin: Date;
  interval: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timeBegin = new Date();
    setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 100);
  }

  tick() {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    this.interval = new Date(currentTime.valueOf() - this.timeBegin.valueOf());
  }
```

Also in your example, you immediate stop the time and as result don't see progress. Try to execute stopTime within subscribe block, for example:

```
GetUser(): void {
    this.startTime();
    this.dataService.getUser().subscribe(res => {
      if (res !== undefined) {
        this.dataIsReady = true;
        this.imgSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + res['image'];
      }
      this.stopTime();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Nice thank you, code is more clean now, but this still doesn't work

Comment: Currently you immediately stop timer and as result you can't see progress. Try to call stopTime in subscribe block.